# Disable Grub bootloader's GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1 after failed startup?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, grubrescue

My title may be incorrect, but I hope I get the idea across...

You know, when you have a failed startup and Grub decides next time it starts up it'll disable the countdown and give you indefinite time to choose your OS? I dont want that.

I have a computer that needs to run 24/7, and has a failsafe that'll restart the computer under some circumstances. This weekend, while I was out of town, I had the computer restart twice-- interrupting the first boot! This disabled the countdown, so the computer sat there in the Grub screen all weekend- which wasn't good, for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Grub's menu from showing up after failed boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178091/how-to-disable-grubs-menu-from-showing-up-after-failed-boot)

Answer (score 0):

My grub is hidden, but it boots everytime without asking. Here is my `/etc/default/grub` :

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
>
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
>
> GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
>
> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
>
> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

This will boot the first entry everytime, without asking. I'm not sure it's recommended if you need to access recovery (but personnaly I have disabled recovery, so...)

Comment: Recovery would be nice. I just want to stop it from not counting down on a failed boot.

Comment: Well, with my answer, recovery would still be there, but I'm not sure how to access it... maybe with a way to un-hide timeout with a key like Shift, but I never managed to make it work. I just chroot my system whenever a problem comes (lazy as ****, I know^^)