# Disable recovery mode

Tags: grub2

I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and in my application I turn on and turn off the system from a energy switch. My problem is the screen presentation of recovery mode. I want to disable it, because I don't have a keyboard to do the selection. Is it possible? I tried

[How to disable recovery mode/single user mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186176/how-to-disable-recovery-mode-single-user-mode)

but it didn't work.

I tried changing

```
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

to

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`, without sucess too.

Comment: Is not `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"` but just `GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"` then type `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I solved my problem with

[How to disable Grub's menu from showing up after failed boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178091/how-to-disable-grubs-menu-from-showing-up-after-failed-boot)

I had the same problem and figured out the following solution:

Open `/etc/default/grub` with an editor

Add a line with this assignment:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=N
```

Set N to the desired timeout in seconds in case of a previously failed boot, for example, 5.

Update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Grub Customizer.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once installed, just type grub-customizer in terminal, to run the program, when it open try to change the default entry under the General settings tab.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: didn't worked Mitch. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I observe that all changes what I do in grub reflects in normal inicialization, but in inicialization after a wrong shutdown, the changes has no effect.