# How to get rid of grub menu after boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, menu

Here is my `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I tried various things including:

[How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up in the beginning of boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot)

[How to disable Grub's menu from showing up after failed boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178091/how-to-disable-grubs-menu-from-showing-up-after-failed-boot)

http://www.itworld.com/software/306238/disable-grub-boot-menu-ubuntu-1210

But I still get grub menu each time I boot.

My generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 45,51,53; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-29-generic-advanced-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-29-generic-recovery-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro splash quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed--ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro splash quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed--ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro splash quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed-root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro recovery nomodeset splash quiet-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro recovery nomodeset splash quiet
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed--ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro splash quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/mapper/isw_beaaegcdjh_ASUS_OS2)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed-root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro recovery nomodeset splash quiet-ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ed6b32bc-ec1d-444c-a000-282fddd6d460 ro recovery nomodeset splash quiet
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: @Rinzwind That is the first thing I tried, but didnt work. Probably because this part of code in generated `grub.cfg`: `set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi`

Comment: Hm, but there is in mine. It even does not respect when I put ` "GRUB_TIMEOUT=5"` it is still 10.

Comment: @Rinzwind Did you mean customizer? What to change? http://i.imgur.com/Kh0Xeej.png

Comment: "show menu" ... but it is off already too :( I gave NO idea why this is going wrong :(

Comment: Is there a way to reset GRUB to default.

Comment: This should be the easiest method: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd