# How to disable boot menu?

Tags: boot, reboot, secure-boot

Sometimes, when I reboot the dirty way, I get a menu (black screen, grey letters) .

This is asking to choose what/how I want to launch Ubuntu (very sorry I dont remind which modes).

**How is it possible to disable it ?** cause the computer has no screen and I dont want boot to be stopped by this screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Grub's menu from showing up after failed boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178091/how-to-disable-grubs-menu-from-showing-up-after-failed-boot)

Comment: Simple solution: Do not hard reboot. Advanced solution: see linked question above.

Comment: @ByteCommander : thank you but... without screen, users do hard reboot to shut down. Unless a better way is possible (w/o screen) ?

Comment: You have a keyboard? I guess without monitor it's a server release without GUI. Can't you configure it to shutdown if you only touch the power button (ACPI settings or something like that) instead of hard-shutdown? Or you could at least use the magic kernel commands (ALT+SYSRQ+R, then +E, +I, +S, +U and +B, waiting a short time for each command to complete.)

Comment: Another possibility is to remote login (I use PuTTY for that) and to start the command `reboot`

Comment: no keyboard, no screen, no login, ... nothing but the on/off button.

Comment: I guess there is at least a LAN connection, otherwise I do not understand what your PC can do nor how you can control/manage it.  If you have a LAN connection, then it must be possible to remotely log on to that machine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the grub boot settings..

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

you need to change this line:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
```

to

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

save configuration file and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

There are also some grub setting applications that can help you with this using a gui.

Comment: @Mackel, thank you. Im about to test it... one stupid question though ? what is the best way to reproduce Grub menu display ?

Comment: may be changing that back to true ?