# Ubuntu doesnt start automactically on startup

Tags: boot, hp

Im using a hp laptop with UEFI . When i turn on my laptop Ubuntu doesn't start automatically and i have to select it manually from the boot options menu every time and its getting annoying. I'm not using dual boot and secure boot.

Comment: It's similar to [How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up at the beginning of boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-at-the-beginning-of-boot) and [How to disable boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673986/how-to-disable-boot-menu).

Comment: does anyone have answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could make GRUB to save you last selection. Open (as sudo)

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

and add these two lines:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Update grub with

```
sudo update-grub
```

You will have to select the entry once more after reboot (for Grub to save it) and then you should be good.

More info about those commands can be found in the [grub official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration)